# How to remove a line with an erroneous number of columns

Tags: bash, awk, sed

I have some data and I need to remove erroneous lines where the column count does not equal the column count defined by the first line of data. Any ideas on how to achieve this with BASH please ?

Data before change:

```
12341234,aa,bb,cc,dd,1231231,23dwef,45645,sfasdf
12341234,aa,bb,cc,dd,1231231,23dwef,45645,sfasdf
12341234,aa,bb,cc,dd,1231231,23dwef,45645,sfasdf
12341
12341234,aa,bb,cc,dd,1231231,23dwef,45645,sfasdf
12341234,aa,bb,cc,
12341234,aa,bb,cc,dd,1231231,23dwef,45645,sfasdf
```

Data after Change:

```
12341234,aa,bb,cc,dd,1231231,23dwef,45645,sfasdf
12341234,aa,bb,cc,dd,1231231,23dwef,45645,sfasdf
12341234,aa,bb,cc,dd,1231231,23dwef,45645,sfasdf
12341234,aa,bb,cc,dd,1231231,23dwef,45645,sfasdf
12341234,aa,bb,cc,dd,1231231,23dwef,45645,sfasdf
```

Comment: Is it possible  that you have a field with a `,` inside? Something like `12341234,"Oops, this one, has , inside, and will fail, for simple solutions",bb,cc,dd,1231231,23dwef,45645,sfasdf`

Comment: The comma will never be within the data- good question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can get the number of fields from first line and compare it with the rest:

```
awk -F, 'NR==1{ count=NF; } NF==count' file
```

Comment: Same concept : `awk -F ',' 'NF==(c=(c==0?NF:c))' YourFile`

Comment: Good answer. But this does not work when the first line is erroneous. Maybe get the correct number of fields as argument?

Comment: @t_thirupathi I considered it too. But first line *is* the *correct* data according to OP: "where the column count does not equal the column count defined by the first line of data".

Comment: That is great the first line is a header, which will always be correct

Comment: @user1654528 If helped you, consider accepting the answer.